# Visual studio way to label watching value

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, watch-window

I am curious is there any way to label value of object in watch window - to help in readability? (Like in the picture) 
It will be really helpful to debug. 
I tried double click on name and changed it, but it looks like we cannot change it.

[How would I like to use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEcWL.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, but you can pin those floating watch windows you get on mouse-over and add comments to those. Also the values stay accessible in between debugging sessions, unlike the watch window, just hover the pin icon in the gutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you want to use is the datatips in debugging.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd.aspx

We hover over a variable to see its value, and it was different from the debugging watch window.

The feature you want to get in the watch window would be hard now.

This document shared us the general features in the debugging watch window:

https://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/26/10-tips-you-should-know-about-watch-window-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/

If you really want to get this request, one idea is that you could submit a feature request to the product team: 
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.